# How do I catch a value change that was changed via a function in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject

My View don't check that's the value has changed. Can you tell me why or can you help me?

You can see below the important code.

My Class

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftyStoreKit

class Foo: ObservableObject {
 @Published var Trigger : Bool = false
  
 func VerifyPurchase() { 
      let appleValidator = AppleReceiptValidator(service: .production, sharedSecret: "your-shared-secret")
      SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(using: appleValidator) { result in
           switch result {
                case .success(let receipt):
                     let productId = "com.musevisions.SwiftyStoreKit.Purchase1"
                     // Verify the purchase of Consumable or NonConsumable
                     let purchaseResult = SwiftyStoreKit.verifyPurchase(
                          productId: productId,
                          inReceipt: receipt) 
                     
                     switch purchaseResult {
                          case .purchased(let receiptItem):
                               print("\(productId) is purchased: \(receiptItem)")
                               
                               self.Trigger.toggle()
                               
                          case .notPurchased:
                               print("The user has never purchased \(productId)")
                               
                               self.Trigger.toggle()
                     }
                case .error(let error):
                     print("Receipt verification failed: \(error)")
                     
                     self.Trigger.toggle()
                     
           }
      }
 } 
}
```

In SceneDelegate my important code at sceneDidbecom to trigger the value to true and then if the function completed, then I want that's trigger back to false

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) { 

      let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

      let foo = Foo()
      let contentView =  ContenView(foo: Foo).environment(\.managedObjectContext, context) 
       
      if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
          let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
          window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
          self.window = window
          window.makeKeyAndVisible()
      }
 }


 func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
 let foo = Foo()
 foo.Trigger = true
 foo.VerifyPurchase()
 }
```

My View that's doesnt update self when the Value has changed.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @ObservedObject var foo: Foo
 
    var body: some View {
      Text(self.foo.Trigger ? "true" : "false")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt` is an asynchronous function and `@Published` variables must be updated on the main thread.

Try adding `DispatchQueue.main.async` when you change the `Trigger` variable in the background:

```
SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(using: appleValidator) { result in
    ...
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.Trigger = false
    }
}
```

Also note that variables in Swift are usually *lowercased* - ie. `trigger` instead of `Trigger`.

---

You're also using two **different** `Foo` instances in your project.

I recommend you remove the code from the `func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene)` and move it to the `.onAppear` in the `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @ObservedObject var foo: Foo
 
    var body: some View {
      Text(self.foo.Trigger ? "true" : "false")
        .onAppear {
            foo.Trigger = true
            foo.VerifyPurchase()
        }
    }
}
```

Also instead of

```
Text(self.foo.Trigger ? "true" : "false")
```

you can do

```
Text(String(describing: self.foo.Trigger))
```